# Values of fourier transform after nyqist limit.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, signal-processing

This was the question on my today's exam on signals and systems:

**We have a continuous function $f(t)$.
Its value of the spectral function at an angular frequency of $8000\pi\ rad/s$ is $\frac{1}{32000}e^{j\frac{\pi}{4}}$.*

*Afterwards, the same signal is sampled at sampling frequency $64000\pi\ rad/s$. Aliasing did not occur. Determine whether it is possible to tell the value of the spectral function of the sampled signal at an angular frequency of $72000\pi\ rad/s$.**

I realized that the maximum frequency I can recover from the signal is $32000\pi$ rad/s. Therefore, I said that we could not recover the spectral function value at angular frequency of $72000\pi$ rad/s.

The correct answer, however, was $e^{j\frac{\pi}{4}}$. I don't see an error in what I said, so I will appreciate any push towards the right answer. Thank you.